# What is $x$ if $x^{x^x} = {(1/2)}^{\sqrt 2}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, alternative-proof

> What is $x$ if $x^{x^x} = {(1/2)}^{\sqrt 2}$?

Answer provided more or less like this :
 \begin{align}{\left(\frac 12\right)}^{\sqrt 2}&=\frac1{2^{\sqrt 2}}\\
2^{\sqrt 2} &= 2^{(2^{(2/4)})} \\
&= 2^{(4^{(1/4)})}\\
& = 4^{1/2(4^{(1/4)})} \\
&= 4^{2^{-1}(4^{(1/4)})} \\
&= 4^{4^{-1/2}(4^{(1/4)})}\\
&= 4^{(4^{(-1/4)})}\\
&= 4^{({1/4}^{(1/4)})}  \\
{\left(\frac 12\right)}^{\sqrt 2} &= \frac1{2^{\sqrt 2}} \\
&= \frac1{4^{({1/4}^{(1/4)})}} \\
&= {\left(\frac14\right)}^{({1/4}^{(1/4)})}  \\
x&=\frac 14\end{align}

Is there more elegant way that show $x=\frac 14$ the only answer?

Edit : source https://youtu.be/d-E5isaIDTA

Comment: well I think your way is a good one, since for another ways you have to you numerical algorithms which are not as elegant as yours

Comment: good solution, indeed. $\to +1$

Comment: It's not the only answer, if you consider the complex plane.  Using numerical methods you find x=2.3528266687 - i * 0.746689357999 works.

Comment: @skbmoore. There are so many solutions in the complex domain !

Comment: Yes Claude, there are.  I was answering the 'is x = 1/4 the only answer?' and it isn't, by showing one countercase.  My guess is that on the real line, which is what the proposer probably meant, there is one positive answer.

Comment: The OP is almost certainly interested only in positive real values for $x$. But their approach only shows that $x=1/4$ is *a* solution, not that it's the *only* solution. I for one am hard pressed to think of a pre-calculus way of ruling out the existence of other (real) solutions. (Indeed, even a calculus-based proof looks like it'll be a little complicated.)

Comment: @Lifeforbetter: Nice approach (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a calculus-based proof that $x=1/4$ is the only positive real solution to the equation $x^{x^x}=(1/2)^\sqrt2$.

It suffices to show that $x^{x^x}$ is increasing for all $x\gt0$. This is clear for $x\ge1$, so it remains to consider what happens for $0\lt x\lt1$. It's convenient to let $x=e^{-u}$ with $u\gt0$, and, after taking logarithms (twice), show that $f(u)=\ln u-ue^{-u}$ is increasing (from $-\infty$ as $u\to0$ to $\infty$ as $u\to\infty$). For this we need to show that

$$f'(u)={1\over u}-(1-u)e^{-u}={1-u(1-u)e^{-u}\over u}\ge0$$

for all $u\gt0$.  But this is clear since $u\gt0$ implies $e^{-u}\lt1$, hence

$$u(1-u)e^{-u}\lt u(1-u)\le{1\over4}\lt1$$

(the maximum for $u(1-u)$ occurring at $u=1/2$).

If there is a non-calculus proof that $x^{x^x}$ is increasing, I'd be keen to see it.